# C# Linking your searchbox to a different websites' searchbox

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there a way to search a different website from within your own website?

for example, I build a ASP.net page with a search box that's linked for example to stackoverflow's search box, when I type in any search query I'll get the results in my website.

Comment: I tried using webclient, but I'm not sure if that's what I need to be using.

Comment: Which website's search results are you trying to scrape? It should be possible to issue a HttpWebRequest, scrape the response and display the results.

It is easier if the site has a search API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to go about doing something like this:

I'll assume that the intent is to make it work with stack overflow

**1. Use StackOverflows Built in API (Client Side)**

You can find some details about it [here](http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/usage). Included in there are details about how to do a search. You can do this with a client side library like jQuery.

```
var URL = "http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/";
var _url = URL + 'users?filter=locrizak';

$.ajax({
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonp: 'jsonp', // <--- add this
    url: _url,
    success: function(val) {
        console.log('success');
    },
    error: function(val) {
        console.log('error');
        console.log(arguments);
    }
 });
```

**2. Use StackOverflows Built in API (Server Side)**

```
static void SearchStackOverflow(string y)
{
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.1/search?intitle=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(y));
    httpWebRequest.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;
    httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    string responseText;
    using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    }
    var result = (SearchResult)new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize(responseText, typeof(SearchResult));
    .... do something with result ...
 }
 class SearchResult
 {
      public List<Question> questions { get; set; }
 }
 class Question
 {
      public string title { get; set; }
      public int answer_count { get; set; }
 }
```

**3. Use a Screen Scraper (Not Ideal When an API is available)**

This can be done with a tool like Selenium or Watin. [Here is a guide to help you get started with Selenium.](http://www.pushtotest.com/selenium-tutorial-for-beginners-blog.html)